# Dynamic jquery pages

Tags: php, jquery

I didn't really know what to call this so I couldn't find anything by searching. Pretty much I have the following:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-ajax]', function(e) {
        var box = $('#ajaxdata');
        e.preventDefault();
        var r = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/betasite/' + r,
            success: function(data) {
                box.html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Pretty much it loads the contents of a file (being some html) into a div so the page doesn't need to reload data as often. The problem is having is that I want to have some php inside that loaded file so I can access server side MySQL data and display it. Whenever I try to do this however, it comments the php out like <--php (stuff) -->. Does anyone know how I can work around that (like having the php generate the page before its loaded)?

Comment: apache already doing that for you....make sure your page saved as .php file.

Comment: ah that might be the problem, I had the files without extensions, let me check edit: Ah that worked. Thanks for the help I probably would not have figured that out for a while.

Comment: its okay brother...cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php code will be rendered by server(WAMP/MAMP) automatically if you are on a local environment. If you are not running a server(WAMP/MAMP) you will have to select one depending on the O/S you use.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'll remember this in the future

Answer (score 0):

a good practice is to test the operation of the service in this case "php", before trying the operation in the front-end (jquery). If you have an Apache server up should see the result of their service by accessing the service route.